# Show already exist data in UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I have class which is the inheritance of `UpdateView`

```
class BotContentsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = BotContents
    template_name = 'bot_contents/bot_contents_edit.html'
    
    form_class = UploadBotContentsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("bot-contents-list")
    success_message = "success!!"
    def get_initial(self):
    
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['name'] = BotContents.name
        return initial 

class UploadBotContentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label="name")
    
    class Meta:
       model = BotContents
       fields = ["name"]
```

in bot_contents_edit.html

```
 {{ form.name }}
```

In this case it shows text box automatically.

It's quite easy but I want to show the original stored data in `BotContents` as placeholder.

I thought `get_initial` is for this purpose , but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render every field in custom way with passing in html: `placeholder={{ form.name.value }}`. You can firstfully check how is field generated automatically and use same classes and ids. It should look something like this:

```
<input 
type="text" 
name="name" 
value=""    # important to leave that empty
maxlength="100" 
class="textinput textInput form-control" 
id="id_name" 
placeholder="{{ form.name.value }}"   # here you pass your name as placeholder
required >
```